# UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3550

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Cuando lanzo una aplicación creada con Eclipse RCP esta siempre aborta con un error de UnsatisfiedLinkError.

```
user@maquina:~> ./aplicacion.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-pi-gtk-3550 or swt-pi-gtk in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:22)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:131)
        at com.app.APPimageProvider.init(APPimageProvider.java:47)
        at com.app.APPclientGUI.<init>(APPclientGUI.java:301)
        at com.app.APPmain.<init>(APPmain.java:77)
        at com.app.APPmain.main(APPmain.java:107)
```

Estoy usando una máquina SLES 11 Release 1.
La librería que dice no encontrar está ubicada en `/usr/lib/libswt-pi-gtk-3550.so`. Es el fichero de librería, no un enlace.
Desinstalar e instalar eclipse no arregla nada.
`ldconfig /usr/lib/libswt-gtk-3550.so` tampoco lo soluciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El swt-pi-gtk-3550 que no encuentra está dentro de un jar :

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
jar xvf /camino/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_3.5.0.v3550b.jar
ls libswt-pi-gtk-3550.so
```

Y de hecho sí que lo encuentra, el mensaje de error de la JVM no es muy bueno. Lo que ocurre es que no puede cargar la librería porque le falta un prerrequisito :

```
ldd libswt-pi-gtk-3550.so
       linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
        libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xf7704000)
        libXtst.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXtst.so.6 (0xf76fd000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf759c000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7581000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf7577000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf74b0000)
        libpcre.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpcre.so.0 (0xf747c000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0xf7349000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0xf7338000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77a9000)
        libxcb-xlib.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xlib.so.0 (0xf7335000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7317000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0xf7312000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf730d000)
```

El "not found" nos indica que falta `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0`
Al instalarlo ya funciona la aplicación

```
zypper install libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

Answer (score 2):

En este hilo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries comentan que se soluciona asi:

> en Ubuntu 12.04 **32 bit**.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
```

> y en Ubuntu 12.04 **64 bit** prueba:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```

Comment: He probado eso así como las otras respuestas de ese hilo y no lo ha solucionado. De todas formas +1 porque la información es útil y relevante y puede que a otras personas sí les sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Analisando con `strace -f -v -s1024 -o/tmp/android.log ./android` se puede ver que las bibliotecas necesarias son creados automaticamente en /tmp/swtlib-64/. Pero si hay:

```
21369 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_C
LOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
21369 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY
|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
21369 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
21369 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 
ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

hay que instalarlo con: `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0` (o equivalente para su sistema).